# bash commands using java process builder for copying file

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder, file-copying

Iam using the following java code for executing bash commands,when trying to copy files the function is returning non zero value but iam able to create files.

copy command : `cp demo.txt /shared`

output is: `127`

create file command : `echo 'sample text' > demo.txt`

output is: `0`

```
public static int run(final String command)  
{
    String[] finalCommand;
    Process process=null;
    int temp=0;

        finalCommand = new String[3];
        finalCommand[0] = "bash";//"/usr/bin/ksh";
        finalCommand[1] = "-c";
        finalCommand[2] = command;

try {
    final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(finalCommand);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    process = processBuilder.start();
    temp=process.waitFor();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
    System.out.println( e.getMessage()); 
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) { 
    System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return temp;
}
```

please help

Comment: Do you have folder /shared and do you have write permission on /shared?

Comment: Print stdout and see what error are you getting

Comment: when you try `cp demo.txt /shared` from shell does it work?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility for cp failing and echo working is due to cp being an external command and echo a built-in command.

An external command can only be found by its file name if the PATH environment variable is set and exported.

But in a situation like this, don't ever rely on PATH - use the full pathname:

```
String command = "/bin/cp demo.txt /shared";
```

Also: Do you have write permission in /shared?